# Element <element> is not a known element warning in Visual Studio when using User controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, user-controls, warnings

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project that is showing the following warning when using User Controls, and I haven’t been able to find a solution anywhere.

> Element `<element>`is not a known element

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 30):

This sounds like a classic re-build your solution and "close and re-open Visual Studio" problem.

It's possible it may also be related to a similar problem I had which I answered at [Resolving "Validation (): Element ‘xxxx’ is not supported" warning in Visual Studio 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474716/resolving-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-warning-in-visual-stud).

Comment: Still happening 12 years later in VS 2019 :) And this is still the fix - restarting VS worked

Answer (score 14):

This can also occur if the element you're trying to add is within the tags of another element that it shouldn't be within.

For Example:

```
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" >
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
</asp:Button>
```

Or in my case, placing an `<asp:Repeater>` in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and forgetting to put it in the `<ContentTemplate>`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">

        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this can also happen if the Namespace name in the .ascx file doesn't match the namespace in the ascx.cs (codebehind) file. Just one more issue to check.

Comment: Inherits="MyControl" was not fully qualified in the ascx.  It should have been Inherits="MyNamespace.MyControl".  That resolved the issue for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the OP:

> The apparent solution to this is to make sure that the TagName is the
>   name of control class.
>
> So for my example, the following displayed the warning:
>
> ```
> <%@ Register Src="~/path/to/Control.ascx" TagName="tagName" TagPrefix="tagprefix" %>
> ```
>
> `<tagprefix:tagName runat="server" id="controlID" />`
>
> But changing it to:
>
> ```
> <%@ Register Src="~/path/to/Control.ascx" TagName="Control" TagPrefix="tagprefix" %>
> ```
>
> `<tagprefix:Control runat="server" id="controlID" />`
>
> fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check you might be on  ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" on Asp.net, so place the code on a new placeholder

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if something's missing in your web.config too.  I just ran into this error while copying a custom control from one solution to another, and the page still couldn't find the element.  If none of the above fixes the problem, check this section of the web.config and make sure your control is included:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="fu" namespace="Fubar.Base" assembly="Fubar" />
    ...
</controls>
```

After adding this, and then closing/reopening the solution, the problem went away.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, it's unnecessary to register the control in the page as well using `@Register`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issur was resolved when I changed the Build Action from "content" to "compile" for the .ascx file and afterwards chaned it back.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when Visual Studio has problems loading assemblies that exist in the `web.config` file.

Take a look at your `web.config` file and make sure that all `<dependentAssembly>` tags have a valid `assemblyIdentity` value.

Take a look at the output window and make sure that there are no error or warning about dependencies, such as:

> Could not load file or assembly `'System.Something.Doesnt.Exist, Version=...` or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
> manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Remove unnecessary or corrupted values and rebuild your solution.