# Resolving "Validation (): Element ‘xxxx’ is not supported" warning in Visual Studio 2005/2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Over the last couple of days I started getting the following validation warning (green squiggly line at design time) in a Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET WebForms project:

> Validation (): Element ‘xxxx’ is not supported.

Where 'xxxx' was a standard ASP.NET server control (asp:panel, asp:container, asp:textbox)

The application would still compile and run but the warnings were an annoyance.

See my answer for the resolution I found.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Delete the files from “C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas” folder (or “…\VisualStudio\8.0\…” if running Visual Studio 2005) in Windows XP. In Windows 7 it is under "C:\Users{User Profile}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft...etc". Remember also the "VisualStudio" part of the path will be different depending on the version installed.

I closed Visual Studio (always a good idea for changes that will affect the IDE), deleted the files then re-opened the project. The warnings were gone.

I found references to this solution at:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1205528.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/04/21/410557.aspx

A quick Google search found the solution.
FYI, the search term I used in Google was “element is not supported”.

I don't know why this happens but I do know there are some flaky domain profile things happening in the network environment.

Comment: Or if you are running Windows 7, the following path is the W7 equivalent: C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Comment: Also do the same in C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas folder

Comment: It appears the contents of the ReflectedSchemas directories are for System.Web-ish builtins, so if you are having an issue with your own **custom controls**, this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution. When using Master pages, this warning may occur when using ContentPlaceHolders to put elements in document sections where they are not allowed, according to your doctype. E.g., putting a div in the head, under xhtml 1.0 Transitional. Removing the offensive elements (i.e., making your page validate), will make the warning disappear.

Comment: Seems in general, this happens when an element is a child of another element it's not allowed to be a child of - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953593/1399272

Answer (score 0):

I had the doctype and html tags wrong. This did work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: A new answer to this old problem is good to see :)
@cskwg Can you tell us what your tags looked like before the change? 
And what version of Visual Studio and .NET were you using? (this is good info for future solution hunters)

Comment: Even <body> caused complaints. I am using visual studio 2019, latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Run VS (2022) under Administrator rights resolved this problem in my opinion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).