# .aspx code errors "Element 'xxxx' is not supported."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting a bunch of these errors for my image buttons, link buttons, text boxes, and labels.  These errors are in my .aspx code.  Why am I getting so many?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmSearchPersonnel.aspx.cs" Inherits="frmSearchPersonnel" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
    <title>Untitled Page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 

    <div align="center"> 


    </div> 

    </div> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search for employee by last name"></asp:Label> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <p> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/frmViewPersonnel.aspx"  
            Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" /> 
    </p> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>.
```

The errors are under Label, TextBox & Button above in blue. The errors state:

> Validation (): Element 'xxxx' is not supported.

Comment: Can you give us the error texts and line numbers please?

Comment: @Rup: Errors are under Label, TextBox, & Button above in blue.  The errors state Validation (): Element 'xxxx' is not supported.

Comment: Did you try closing the files in Visual Studio and reopening it, seeing if the errors go away? Seems to recall this happening sometimes on newly created files.

Comment: My best guess then is that you've somehow lost the asp: namespace definition. You haven't done a `<clear/>` in `<pages><controls>` in your web.config?

Comment: @DoozerBlake:  Yeah I tried that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474716/resolving-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-warning-in-visual-stu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem I & my Resharper see is the period after the ending html tag.

```
</html>.
```

What are the errors you are getting?

**Edit:**

Here's a simple fix someone had:

http://weblogs.asp.net/alaaalnajjar/archive/2010/08/31/how-to-fix-quot-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-quot-visual-studio-2010.aspx

> the idea is to remove the folder "ReflectedSchemas" from paths:
>
> **Win XP** : C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
>
> **Win Vista / 7**: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming
>   \Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
>
> Note: make sure that "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" is
>   selected from Folder Options,also don't forget to close VS before
>   deleting the folder.
>
> This solution should work for VS2010 and VS2008,at VS2008 you have to
>   delete ReflectedSchemas from folder 9.0 not 10.0.

Comment: That ought not cause compile errors, though - as far as ASP.NET's concerned that's just extra text to emit into the HTML page. But yeah, I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: @Ed B: The errors state Validation (): Element 'xxxx' is not supported.

Comment: Try this fix i added above..looks pretty simple

Comment: thanx it works. for windows 7 + vs 2010 i am facing same issue. now resolve.

Answer (score 6):

This issue has been reported before. I found an article with steps to resolve:

> 1. Close down Visual Studio 2008 (or Visual Studio 2010).
> 2. Go to Control Panel -> Appearances and Personalization -> Folder Options -> then select the View tab.  Now make sure "Show hidden
>      files, folders, and drives" is selected and click OK.
> 3. Now browse to the following folder:  Computer -> OS (C:) -> Users -> {username} -> AppData -> Roaming -> Microsoft -> VisualStudio -> 9.0 folder.  Note: in Visual Studio 2010 would be 10.0 folder.
> 4. Now delete the "ReflectedSchemes" folder.  This should fix "Validation (): Element '' is not supported" error for ASP.NET server
>      controls within Visual Studio 2008.
> 5. After reopening your Visual Studio 2008 project, you should now have intellisense working correctly for ASP.NET server controls.

See here for more details:
 http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-validation-element-not-supported-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I am working through Citrix.  I don't think I have access to that folder.

Comment: You should do - it's inside your profile. If you can't see the dirs then try typing the path as there will be hidden folders in there. If you're on a pre-Vista system look for `\Documents and Settings\Mike\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0` etc.

Comment: Hey thanx works for me on windows 7 + vs 2010..nice jobs

Answer (score 2):

add this in your page.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">
```

istead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 1):

In hopes of helping someone else from a google search like mine:

Visual Studio 2013 - I did the same as suggested by the others deleting the "ReflectedSchemes" folders to no avail.

Finally, I deleted `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` - then replaced it and the problem suddenly went away.   Come to think of it, seems like I've done this before too.

FWIW....

Answer (score 1):

Noticed I had to delete the contents of ReflectedSchemas in:

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas\

and

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas\

also followed the reset VS2010 settings:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=VS.100).aspx

to get it to clear the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those that deleting of "ReflectedSchemas" folder has not worked - do following

- Close Visual Studio
- Try again to delete (Windows 7 paths):

```
    C:\Users\DefaultAppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
    C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
    C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
    C:\Users\[your_nt_name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
    C:\Users\[your_nt_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
```

- For me above has not worked, so I simply copied whole folder

Users[your_nt_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio

from another machine where these problems did not occur. After this all ASP.net IntelliSence problems were gone.

I'm keeping compressed backup of VistualStudio folder in case this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the target validation to "HTML 5" and click OK, Element is an HTML 5 supported validation so it can not supported in XHTML1.0

Refer Below Screenshot [Set Vadation to HTML5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nktT5.png)