# "Element 'title' is not supported" - what does it mean and how can it be fixed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm using VS2005 to create an ASP.NET website, and in one of my aspx files I noticed that the `<title>` element was underlined in red. And the mouseover tooltip said "Element 'title' is not supported".
Since I didn't know what could cause this, I looked it up on Google, and to my surprise Google said it couldn't find the exact text (in quotes).

So now I want to know

- What does this error mean?
- How can I get rid of it?

This is what my aspx looks like (after removing the content from the body; the error remains)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="upload" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head><title>Upload</title></head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about [using Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Element+is+not+supported+asp.net) instead?

Comment: Yes, there are many results for `element is not supported`. But I wanted to find this specific one... I never encountered a situation where `<title>` was disallowed. Bing also doesn't show any results for the exact text in quotes.

Comment: @Mat why did you change my question?

Comment: @MrLister: because your title was terrible and didn't say anything about your actual problem. (And whether or not you are the first in seeing this is of no practical use.)

Comment: @MrLister: It doesn't help that you haven't shown what your markup looks like. There are plenty of places where `<title>` isn't allowed, as far as I'm aware. Perhaps you missed putting it in the `<head>` element?

Comment: @JonSkeet No, no. If you put a title anywhere else, or you put a title in twice by mistake, you get entirely different errors. Errors that I could deal with!

Comment: @MrLister: Right - so that's not the same as "I never encountered a situation where `<title>` was disallowed."

Comment: I copied your markup into VS2005 and interestingly I got `<html>` underlined in red with the error "Element 'html' is missing required attribute 'xmlns'".

Comment: You have VS's validation scheme set to XHTML. Change it to HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a Visual Studio update, the error condition hasn't returned. So let's just chalk it up to a bad VS installation.

That doesn't explain why it only occurred in that one project, but as I haven't been able to duplicate the problem, let's just close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Agains what XHTML conformance did u set the ASP.NET page? It should be XHTML 1.0 or higher

PS: I found another answer on google, also on stackoverflow:
[.aspx code errors "Element 'xxxx' is not supported."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169447/aspx-code-errors-element-xxxx-is-not-supported)

Or else did u satisfy to the requirements of the title element?

"The title element must not contain other elements, only text. Only one title element is permitted in a document."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why should it be XHTML 1.0 or higher?

Comment: can u post the code of your page in your question? It should contain <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: The question you link to only mentions the error for `asp:` controls, not for plain HTML ones. I often get that too, and as the answers sao over there, can resolve that by closing and reopening the file. But I'm afraid this is something else. E.G. why should the error occur only on the `<title>` tag and not on `<html>`, `<head>` etc?

Comment: I use the HTML doctype, because the resulting file is HTML and I don't like using XHTML doctypes for HTML. Besides, XHTML is on its way out, you know that. Internet Explorer never really was into XHTML either. Let's stick with HTML, OK?

Comment: Could u try visual studio 2008 or 2010?

Comment: It might be a compilation error, is there any other error or warning visible? Does it work without a title? Does the code behind file exist, is the name really "Upload", etc..

Answer (score 0):

The `title` element is only allowed inside the `head` element.

A likely reason why Visual Studio would say that the element is not supported would be that it thinks that it's not inside the `head` element. You may have some error in the HTML code that makes the `head` element invalid, or you might actually have placed the `title` outside the `head` element.

Comment: That's what Jon said, but you'd get different errors in that case.