# VS 2010 produces Validation error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I Just crate a new WebApplication project, and from site.master is the code

```
    <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="WebTestApp.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The asp:Content which is inside the head works fine (without Validation Error)
All the other asp: controls gives me the error 
Warning 13  Validation (): Element 'contentplaceholder' is not supported.
And that hppen in all controls (not only in the ContentPlaceHolder).
Of course the same issue I'm face in the Default.aspx file.

Comment: I'd try opening and closing the page, the solution, and if neither of those work, try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: I did all of those, have in mind that this test project was started by the default from Visual Studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474716/resolving-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-warning-in-visual-stu

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1205528.aspx

Comment: @Joe Please post your answer corectly in order to give your credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resolving "Validation (): Element ‘xxxx’ is not supported" warning in Visual Studio 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474716/resolving-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-warning-in-visual-stu)

Delete the files from “C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas” folder (or “…\VisualStudio\8.0\…” if running Visual Studio 2005) in Windows XP. In Windows 7 it is under "C:\Users{User Profile}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft...etc". Remember also the "VisualStudio" part of the path will be different depending on the version installed.

Answer (score 0):

please post your code including the default page. Check also your default.aspx if the content place holder matched with the place holders on the master page.

hope it helps.

Comment: The right answer was give it from Joe. I have the filling Google had to do something with this problem... any way i solve it.