# AJAX controls get error "Element is not a known element"

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, visual-studio-2019

I've been working on an ASP.NET web application and I recently got a new laptop. I was using Visual Studio Community 2019 using .NET Framework 4.7.2 on my old laptop, so I made sure to get the exact same software/version on my new one. I used Git to clone my project on my new laptop so I'm sure everything is the same. Both laptops are running Windows 10 Home edition.

For some reason on my new laptop, when viewing a .aspx page, the AJAX controls are underlined in green, and when I hover over them with my cursor, I see an error message saying "Element 'x' is not a known element." This happens with all the AJAX controls and with other controls defined within the AJAX controls. Strangely, if I view another .aspx page, the AJAX controls on that page are recognized. What I noticed is whichever .aspx page is opened first will have the unrecognized AJAX controls error, and all other .aspx pages won't have it. Also strange is the project seems to work just fine when I run it, with the AJAX controls that aren't recognized working normally.

The same project open on my old laptop doesn't have this problem. Am I missing some dll file on my new computer? How would I be able to tell what's missing?

Comment: Additional info: I already tried uninstalling Visual Studio and it didn't help. I created a simple VS project to test this and I saw the same error. I put some basic AJAX controls on the about.aspx page. When opened on my old laptop, this project has no errors. On my new laptop, the AJAX controls on whichever .aspx page I open first have the error. Here's the Git repo for that project if you're curious: https://github.com/jashawoo/WebApplication1

Comment: Maybe these threads can help you. [Element 'X' is not a known element...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550589/element-x-is-not-a-known-element-web-application); [Element <element> is not a known element...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492027/element-element-is-not-a-known-element-warning-in-visual-studio-when-using-use).

Comment: Are these MS AJAX controls, or AJAX Control Toolkit controls? Whichever one it is, or both, are they showing up in the toolbox?

Comment: Some dll's I have that might be relevant: `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll`; 
`Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll`;
`Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll`; `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`.